# How to read one jpg file as php htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mime-types

so I have a directory which contains many JPG files like this:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
loll.jpg
image.jpg
```

i know this code with read all files jpg as php

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php52 .jpg
```

but i want to focus juts on one file  image.jpg

so i want to create an ht access file to read just the file image.jpg as a php file while other images can be displayed normally as a jpg

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In site root .htaccess you can use this rule to set MIMI-type for a particular image file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (?:^|/)image\.jpg$ - [T=application/x-httpd-php]
```

[Apache documentation of flag `T`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_t) says that:

> Sets the `MIME` type with which the resulting response will be sent. This has the same effect as the **`AddType` directive**.

Comment: ihave tried it sir but the result is when i want to execute the http://localhost/images/image.jpg  , the browser ask me to download the file

Comment: Does `localhost/images/image.jpg` exist as a valid file?

Comment: Try updated rule. On my Apache, it displays content of `image.jpg` (which has some PHP sample code)

Comment: i have tried but nothing changed

is ther any valid  htaccess code  to try  it !

Comment: This is a working solution tested on my Apache. You  should just copy paste this in a blank htaccess and then test.